# PHP echo all file contents after exploding

Tags: php, echo, explode

I've got a file of the countries and want to echo all of its contents after exploding.

I explode it with a new line.

Here is the code:

```
$file = "countries.txt";

$gfuc = fopen($file ,"r");

$gcontent = fread($gfuc, 5000);

$expc = explode("\n", $gcontent);
```

Is it possible to get all results in the new line without writing $expc[0] $expc[1], etc. ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I correctly understand your issue: `implode('', $expc)`

Comment: what's the purpose of reading the file contents into the array when you are only outputting it? why not just do `fpassthru('countries.txt')`? or `echo nl2br(file_get_contents('countries.txt'));` in case you want to turn the newlines into br elements.

Comment: Rather than use fread and then explode on new lines, why not simply use PHP's file() function - http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php - that gives you an array in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You loop this `$expc` array:

```
foreach ( $expc as $item ) {
  echo $item . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: if that's what the OP wants, OP can write `echo nl2br(file_get_contents('countries.txt'));`

Answer (score 0):

do with:

```
foreach( $expc as $val  ){
   echo $val . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($expc as $output)
{
    echo $output.'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `print_r($expc)` or `var_dump($expc)`.

Comment: see `Is it possible to get all results in the new line without writing $expc[0] $expc[1], etc.`

Comment: These two are more suited for debugging than creating "user-facing" output.

Answer (score 0):

http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

"file_get_contents — Reads entire file into a string"

OR

file() — Reads entire file into an array

```
$expc = file($file);
echo implode("\n", $expc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course,

If it's for debugging purposes use [print_r()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

Otherwise, use a foreach loop:

```
foreach($expc as $eK => $eV)
{
    echo "Element " . $eK . " is: " . $eV . "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var_dump($expc);

var_dump() is a very Good Method to Check Arrays or vars